# Row striped don't working in angular *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to apply a effect row stripped in my rows that have a *nfFor, but apparently the class are applying the gray background in all rows.

I try something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row ml-4" *ngIf="visivel">
  <div class="divJanelaResultadoParcial" id="autocompletar" class="col-xl-9 divJanelaResultadoParcial">
    <a class="divJanelaProduto" *ngFor="let produto of produtos" [routerLink]="['/produtos', produto.id, produto.slug]" >
      <div class="row linhaProduto row-striped">

        <div class="col-3">
          <img class="img" src="{{ produto.foto_prin_1 }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <span class="ml-2">{{ produto.nome }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <span class="ml-2">{{ produto.preco | currency:'BRL' }}</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img {
        width:60px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .divJanelaResultadoParcial{
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .linhaProduto{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }


    .row-striped:nth-of-type(odd){
        background-color: #efefef;
      }

      .row-striped:nth-of-type(even){
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the even and odd functionality from ngFor.

`*ngFor="let produto of produtos; let even = even; let odd = odd"`

---

```html
<div class="row ml-4" *ngIf="visivel">
  <div class="divJanelaResultadoParcial" id="autocompletar" class="col-xl-9 divJanelaResultadoParcial">
    <a class="divJanelaProduto" *ngFor="let produto of produtos; let even = even; let odd = odd" [routerLink]="['/produtos', produto.id, produto.slug]">
      <div class="row linhaProduto row-striped" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">

        <div class="col-3">
          <img class="img" src="{{ produto.foto_prin_1 }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <span class="ml-2">{{ produto.nome }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <span class="ml-2">{{ produto.preco | currency:'BRL' }}</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.row-striped.even {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.row-striped.odd {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor is not to identify item but to make a loop.

If you wish to make a striped effect try this:

**HTML:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6]; let odd = odd">
    <p [class.odd]="odd">item</p>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.odd{
  background:grey
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uahzxa)